# Unexpected number of calls inside the `std::views::transform`

Tags: c++, c++20

The program below creates a view `v1` of the vector `v` using the `std::views::transform`, which calls the function `square` a number of times, equal to the length of the vector - which is understandable.

Another view `v2` is created by a chain of two range adaptors - the same `std::views::transform` as before and the `std::views::filter`, and the latter one filters out odd numbers. In this case the function `square` is called more times, than I expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

auto countSquare = 0;
auto square(int const X) {++countSquare; return X * X;}

auto countIsEven = 0;
auto isEven(int const X) {++countIsEven; return X % 2 == 0;}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
  // ------ apply function 'square'
  countSquare = 0;
  auto v1 = v | std::views::transform(square);
  std::ranges::copy(v1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\t")); cout << endl;
  cout << "countSquare = " << countSquare << endl;
  // ------ apply functions 'square' and 'isEven': the 'square' is called 6 times !!!
  countSquare = countIsEven = 0;
  auto v2 = v | std::views::transform(square) | std::views::filter(isEven);
  std::ranges::copy(v2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\t")); cout << endl;
  cout << "countSquare = " << countSquare << endl;
  cout << "countIsEven = " << countIsEven << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
1   4   9   16  
countSquare = 4
4   16  
countSquare = 6
countIsEven = 4
```

The number of the function `square` calls in the second case is more than in the first case - why is that?

Compiler/OS: g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0

Comment: That's the weird way range views work. I'm not sure, but I think first it determines al the squares and looks which results are even, that's 4, and then it transform the input values that gave an even result _again_ in the output copy, that's an additional 2. Ranges are quite inefficient this way imho

Comment: Because `views::filter` caches the result, which does extra work. [range.filter#view-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter#view-5).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that a transform view stores a base view object and a transformation function object `tf`. Its iterator type simply wraps an iterator of the base view and dereferencing it gives you `tf(*iBase)`. A filter view similarly stores a base view and a function object `pred` representing the predicate. But, its iterator type has to call the equivalent of `std::ranges::find_if(remainder, pred)`, applying `pred` to the result of dereferencing the remaining base view iterators. Your `v2` example therefore results in this sequence:

```
// begin() of v and transform_view
isEven(square(1)); // false
isEven(square(2)); // true
// begin() of the filter_view
square(2);         // 4
isEven(square(3)); // false
isEven(square(4)); // true
square(4);         // 16
// end() of all views reached
```

This is a side effect of views working exclusively with iterators, being agnostic of what they represent.